# CentOS 6.5 have to manually add the default route

Tags: networking, centos, route

With CentOS 6.5 on an R710 I have to manually remove the default route; and `sleep 10` before adding it back otherwise the interfaces do not use the default route that was added upon boot.

There are no errors in `/var/log/messages` and I've seen this issue on another R710 server we have.

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `DELAY=60` to network interface configuration files seems to have fixed the issue.